# Android Wear Custom Voice Actions

Tags: android, speech-recognition, wear-os

I'm making an app that will work with Android Wear,
And I wanted to implement a command into Google's "Ok Google" option.
I saw this page:
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html

But it's related only to apps that include Activities in the Android Wear.

I wanted to ask:

1. Can I add custom commands? I mean, those who does not start with the word "Start"?
2. Can I add commands that will do another thing than just opening the app? Like running a method?

If it's not the place to ask this, can you give me an email/link to Google Developers help/support? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For apps that run on the Android Wear Device:

1. No, the list of system-provided voice actions is fixed (and listed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#SystemProvided)). You can set your application to be able to respond to them (for example, to *take a note*), but you cannot add new ones.
2. Yes. When already inside your app, you you can use `startActivityForResult()` using the `ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` to get voice input. You could then use the returned string to execute whatever you want.

Meanwhile, if you're just [displaying notifications from an Android app running in a handheld](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/index.html), then you cannot presently have *voice actions* at all (at least in a literal sense). What you may have, though, is a notification action that [requests voice input](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html). That input will then be passed as an extra in the Intent that is delivered to the app in the handheld.

Comment: An app that is controlled by it's notification on the Wear.

Comment: In the 2nd question I also meant to the Ok Google of the Android Wear.

Comment: @user3184899 Ok, edited answer, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can you show me how to add a wearable activity to an existing app?

Comment: @user3184899 Follow the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html It's pretty well explained.