# Cue Card with custom Voice Suggestions

Tags: wear-os

https://developer.android.com/design/wear/patterns.html#Countdown states

> The cue card can be invoked to continue specifying the action. For
>   example in a messaging application, tapping a “Reply” action button
>   invokes the Cue Card and prompts for voice input. In this case the
>   prompt label (such as “Speak your message…”) and a set of sample voice
>   suggestions can be specified by developers.

I want to have a wear application, which when launched could show a Cue Card with my custom voice suggestions. How can I do it?

Comment: I would also like to know how ca a custom voice action can be added to the system cue card. Something similar to "Set alarm" but with a custom label and which would start some activity from my wear app. So far, I saw in the docs that you can only register to a default action or add an activity that the user can run by saying "Start Your Activity Name". - https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a similar question and here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543484/android-wear-custom-voice-actions).
The [Android documentation for voice commands](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html) also implies the same thing: you cannot add custom commands, but you can invoke the voice recognition activity and handle the input from that.