# Voice to Text with Moto 360

Tags: android, wear-os, voice-recognition, moto-360

I'm trying to create an Android Wear project, which I can translate the voice in my Moto 360 to String, for example, when the user say "Hello" I get the String "hello".

can anyone help me , i need little explanation for the communitation between the android app and the wear.

and thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543484/android-wear-custom-voice-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain speech input inside the application just like on any other android application:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#FreeFormSpeech

You can also add custom voice actions to invoke your application.